# SSIS not refreshing then I remove a column from an OLD DB Source

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

In my dataflow task I have an OLEDB Data source where I select column A, B, and C.  I then have a lookup connected to the source. When I go to the columns in the lookup I see A, B, and C for available input columns.  Everything is good.  I then go back to my Data source and remove column C.  When I go back to Columns in the lookup task Column C is still in the available input columns.  How can I refresh this?  I don't want to delete and re add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete from the source column.
2. There now should be error shown on lookup element.
3. Just go in lookup element and push OK, error should be gone.

If you saying that there still column is, you need to delete the line which is connecting OLE DB source and Lookup element. After that just connect again OLE DB source and Lookup elements. Again there should be error on lookup element just go in lookup element and push OK...

Comment: I did everything you recommended and the removed column still is still listed in the lookup task.  Any other ideas?

Comment: hm, maybe you insert  screenshot ole db source without C and lookup with C column... I have never experienced such a problem, my only guess would be what there is some other element between lookoup and source elements, or in source element there a still some column, or some SSIS package properties or error properties what don't eveluate  package after you delete column...